# Изображения в тексте HTML

Tags: css3, html, css

Итак, есть текст и картинка. Подскажите, как с помощью свойств css для текста и картинки сделать так, чтобы:

1. Выровнять изображение в тексте по центру без обтекания;
2. Выровнять изображение в тексте с обтеканием по левому краю;
3. Выровнять изображение в тексте с обтеканием по правому краю;
4. Выровнять изображение в тексте без обтекания по левому краю;
5. Выровнять изображение в тексте без обтекания по правому краю;
6. Выровнять изображение и текст на одну линию (Например, при использовании смайликов нужно вставлять их на одном уровне с текстом)

Код HTML:

```
<p>Hello <img src="#" /> world</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Выравнивание с обтеканием**

```
 img{
    float: right | left | none | inherit
 }
```

Про float написано [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) и [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/float).

**Выравнивание без обтекания**

```
 img{
  float: right | left | inherit
 }

 p{
  clear: none | left | right | both | inherit
 }
```

Про "clear" прочитайте [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/clear) и [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp).

**Относительно выравнивания текста и изображения в одну линию** можете прочитать и посмотреть примеры со свойствам: [vertical-align](http://htmlbook.ru/css/vertical-align). Также можно выравнять изображение и текст без CSS:

`<img src="#" align="top | texttop | absmiddle | right | left | bottom | baseline">`

Также, стоит запомнить, что к примеру "[position](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position): absolute" снимает все возможные обтекания элемента, которому мы присвоили данное значение.

"|" - означает "или", т.е. Вы можете оставить только одно из перечисленных свойств.